# Python, Windows service Import error

Tags: python, windows, service, windows-services

I am trying to run a python application as a Windows Service. The code I have installs and starts but I am having issues importing modules and classes which are part of the application.

Note:: Python libraries are being included fine.

I have checked the python path and all the correct values are in there, (including the application directory) which is leading me to believe that the windows service could be running in a different location.

Does a python application running as a windows service get run from a different location on windows?

Comment: When you say "run from a different location" do you mean the current working directory of the process?

Comment: It runs as a different user, usually the system user. so if you have some user specific environment variables that you are depended on (hint: `%PATH%`) then that might be the issue.

Comment: @NathanHoad yes sorry a different location from the current working directory

Comment: @zenpoy which user would the service run as by default? Even if the application did run as a different user would the application directory not already be on the path?

Comment: @mattwritescode you could find that out pretty easily, with `os.getcwd()`

Comment: @mattwritescode - 1) the service runs as `system` as far as I know. 2) use `os.chdir` to change the current working directory to the one you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks, between you both I have managed to sort the issue. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python service creation using `win32service` created the pythonservice.exe in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32` by default.

you can perform `os.chdir(yourdir)` in your code just before service creation,

the best thing would be use absolute paths and setting proper sys.path within your script for accessing files